# How to calculate cosine similarity of 2 vectors when the element of each vectors has different range

Tags: java, algorithm, math

How do I find the cosine similarity between two vectors and each element of the vector has different range?
For example, each vector has two elements, `V = {v[0], v[1]}`, such as {age, height},where age ranges from 30 to 70, and height ranges from 100cm - 200 cm, two example vectors, `v1 = {20, 175}, v2 = {35,192}` are given.

I know that cosine similarity (`sim`) is defined as `sim = (v1 dot v2 ) / (|v1| * |v2|)`, where dot is the dot product between v1 and v2, |v| is the magnitude of a vector. But this is based on the assumption of the each element in vector V has same range of data and it is not applied when each element has different range, such as the case I used here.

One thing I can think of is to apply a weights vector `W = {w[0],w[1]}` to each vector v1, and v2 here to normalize each element in vector.

That is

```
weighted_sim = ( sum (w[i] * v1[i] * v2[i]) )  / sqrt ( (sum (w[i] *v1[i]^2 ) ) * ( sum (w[i] *v2[i]^2 ) ) )
```

But I have difficult to figure out the weights vector W here.

Could someone help me here? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Wouldn't you simply normalise both measurements to lie in the range `[0,1]` ?  So normalised age would be `(real_age-30)/(70-30)` ?  Of course, this isn't a simply multiplicative 'weight'; I'd first calculate the normalised vectors, then the vector similarity.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the normalisation depends on the data distribution. For example, if age are linearly distributed between 30-40, the linear normalisation you mentioned will work, otherwise it will create extra problem here.

Comment: Oh well, you'll need cleverer answers than I can provide then.

Comment: In this all you will be doing by scaling one or other or both dimensions will be to effectively scale one dimension and though this will change your result of sim it will not change some fundamental points about it such as if it was 1 before it will be 1 after. Also iof sim1>sim2 before then it will be after. I'm not sure what you are doing with your sim afterwards but you may find that it isn't a big deal...

Comment: Thanks, Chris. I intend to combine the cosine similarity and the euclidean distance together in a weighted form there to measure the difference between two vectors. Euclidean distance gives the magnitude difference but not angle difference. Cosine distance has the opposite result here. So I intend to combine two together in a weighted form of distance metric here. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'd simply normalise both measurements to lie in the range [0,1]. So normalised age would be `(real_age-30)/(70-30)` and normalised height would be `(real_height-100)/(200-100)`.  I note that your example vector `V1` has an age of 20, which lies outside the range you've specified.

These calculations don't give you weights that you can apply to your raw data by a simple multiplication.  I would first calculate the normalised vectors, then the vector similarity between them.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, mark. Also since the cosine similarity gives use the angle difference between two vectors, and the euclidean distance gives us the magnitude difference between two vectors, here. Is there any way we can combine both cosine distance and euclidean distance together in weighted form to represent final distance metrics here. Thanks.

Comment: I don't know any widely-used ways of combining the distance metrics as you wish, I expect you can think of something *ad-hoc* which satisfies your requirements better than I can.

Answer (score 1):

You might be after standardization, but that requires more data than only two input vectors. Weighting is applied when you want to give one of the features (I'm considering these as two features) more/less importance than the other one.

As an example, I artificially considered the entire range (in integer steps) for applying standardization and compared your single example against normalization and no procedure (i.e., do nothing with the data). This is the result:

```
(standardization) Similarity: 0.744599          Data: (-1.12599, 0.88339), (-0.259844, 1.47232).
(  normalization) Similarity: 0.978736          Data: (0.166667, 0.75), (0.416667, 0.92).
(           none) Similarity: 0.997788          Data: (20, 175), (35, 192).
```

The result using standardization makes more sense to me at least.

Here is sample basic code for producing the above:

```
import numpy

def cosine_dist(a, b): # Similarity between a and b
    return sum(a * b) / ((sum(a ** 2) * sum(b ** 2)) ** 0.5)


age_range = [10., 70.]
height_range = [100., 200.]

# Input.
age = numpy.array([20, 35])
height = numpy.array([175, 192])

# Normalization
age_n = numpy.array(age, dtype=float)
height_n = numpy.array(height, dtype=float)
age_n = (age_n - age_range[0]) / (age_range[1] - age_range[0])
height_n = (height_n - height_range[0]) / (height_range[1] - height_range[0])

# Standardization.
all_age = numpy.array(range(*map(int, age_range)))
all_height = numpy.array(range(*map(int, height_range)))
age_s = numpy.array(age, dtype=float)
height_s = numpy.array(height, dtype=float)
age_s = (age_s - all_age.mean()) / all_age.std()
height_s = (height_s - all_height.mean()) / all_height.std()

for name, a, h in [('standardization', age_s, height_s),
        ('normalization', age_n, height_n), ('none', age, height)]:

    data = numpy.array([(a[0], h[0]), (a[1], h[1])])
    data_s = '(%g, %g), (%g, %g)' % (data[0][0], data[0][1], data[1][0], data[1][1])
    print "(%15s) Similarity: %g\t\tData: %s." % (name, cosine_dist(*data),
            data_s)
```